# detect when youtube video ends - javascript - not working

Tags: javascript, video, youtube

I have youtube videos in db (only urls of them). they are in this form:

http://www.youtube.com/embed/CT1909pdGBU

now, I want to detect when videos ends and show something else in place of video container.

I tried these steps:

```
1. changed the above youtube url to:
```

http://www.youtube.com/embed/CT1909pdGBU?version=3&enablejsapi=1

```
2. added this js code in videopage.html

    var player;
    function onYouTubePlayerAPIReady() {
        alert('api ready!');
        player = new YT.Player('player', {
          events: {
            'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
          }
        });
    }
    // when video ends
    function onPlayerStateChange(event) {
        if(event.data === 0) {
            alert('done');
        }
    }
```

But I am getting neither `"api ready!"` nor `"done"` alerts.. what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it was easy:

```
    var tag = document.createElement('script');
    tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
    var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
    firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);

    var player;
    function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
        player = new YT.Player('myyoutubevideo_iframe_div', {
            height: '410',
            width: '100%',
            videoId: '{{ video.yt_id }}',
            events: {
                'onReady': onPlayerReady,
                'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
            }
        });
    }
    function onPlayerReady(event) {
        event.target.playVideo();
    }
    var done = false;
    function onPlayerStateChange(event) {
        if (event.data == YT.PlayerState.ENDED) {
            $('#myyoutubevideo_iframe_div').hide();
            $('#aftervideo_div').show();
        }
    }
```